# how to pass i18n data $t as prop to a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

**in a normal way with out translation but i want to translate the two object array and bind into a component**

```
<InfoNews 
           v-for="infonew in infonews"
            :id="infonew.id"
            :title="infonew.title"
            :content="infonew.content"
          />
 data() {
    return {
     infonews: [
        {
          id: "01",
          title: "what we do",
          content:"industke aecimen book. ",
        },
        {
          id: "02",
          title: "our mission",
          content:"ggdddg",
           
        },
      ],
    };
```

Comment: I do real understand what you means? Do you want to render two  `<info-news/>`?

Comment: yes i do what to render two info news and should have translation in both using $t how should i do it help

Comment: Are you able to render without $t? Please, provide a valid code, not truncated snippets. It's unclear what exactly you do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It should be not `'title'` string but some `title` variable (property) name that needs to be provided to $t but that's all that can be said at this moment

Comment: yes i do i need to be able to translate two object of information and render it to info component in any way and i know i $t  does not work in data how can i go arroud with computed property

Answer (score 0):

Make `infonews` a computed property. The `title` and `content` of each should be the translation keys.

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    infonews() {
      return [
        {
          id: "01",
          title: this.$t("what we do"),
          content: this.$t("industke aecimen book"),
        },
        {
          id: "02",
          title: this.$t("our mission"),
          content: this.$t("ggdddg"),
        },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank's bro very much it worked u understand what i meant@j.Titus

Comment: you're welcome @E.RAY